# Having trouble with PCIe passthrough

Tags: usb, gpu, pcie

My KVM/qemu host is running Ubuntu 16.04. I'd like to do passthrough of a GPU and a USB controller. The passthrough of the GPU seems to be working by blacklisting the nouveau module:

`[   18.217858] pci-stub: add 10DE:06FD sub=FFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFF cls=00000000/00000000
[   18.217872] pci-stub 0000:03:00.0: claimed by stub`

However, there is one problem: I do not have a console output on the VGA port of the onboard GPU anymore. How can I tell the kernel to use a specific GPU for boot messages, shell etc?

As for the USB controller, there is no stub created. I expect this is because the hub driver loads before pci_stub. I have added hub to the blacklist and then also added it to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` in order to make USB function at all.

This does not work - pci_stub does not claim the device.

How can I stop the host from interacting with one of three USB controllers?